# App Engine: How to redirect from outside of a class

Tags: python, google-app-engine, redirect, webapp2

So I know you can redirect in GAE from within a class that inherits from `webapp2.RequestHanlder` using this:

```
class Foo(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect('https://google.com')
```

While this works, it would be great to be able to perform a redirect outside of a class.

For example, say you have the following code that is a global function - i.e. it does not exist inside of a class:

```
def fetch_url(url, method=urlfetch.GET, data=''):
    """Send a HTTP request"""

    result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url, method=method, payload=data,
                            headers={'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'})

    return result.content
```

If you could redirect from the function, you could check the status code and redirect to an error page. E.g.

```
if result.status_code != 200:
    urllib2.urlopen('/error_page.html')
    return
```

Unfortunately, the above code does nothing in GAE and the following warning is generated.

```
WARNING  2014-05-22 21:58:24,364 urlfetch_stub.py:482] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Host']
```

So is there a way to perform a redirect outside of a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own `Exception` subclass to handle redirects.

The way I do this is to make my own subclass of `webapp2.RequestHandler` that overrides the `handle_exception` method ([See the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requesthandlerclass#RequestHandler_handle_exception))

```
class RedirectError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, new_url):
        self.new_url = new_url

class MyWebappFramework(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def handle_exception(self, exception, debug_mode):
        if isinstance(exception, RedirectError):
            self.redirect(exception.new_url)
        else:
            super(MyWebappFramework, self).handle_exception(exception, debug_mode)
```

Using this functionality, you can actually make a wide range of custom exceptions to easily manage expectations. For example, you might also make a `NotFound` exception to set the status code to 404 and render a "Page not found" message.

To make the redirect occur, raise the `RedirectError`.

it's as simple as `raise RedirectError("http://www.google.com")`.

Comment: For fun, here are some errors I've implemented: ``[NotFoundError, LoginRequiredError, LoginUnderPrivileged, ForbiddenError, RedirectError]``

Comment: So I get this when I implement your code:   
    File "/Users/bengrunfeld/Desktop/Work/code/wf-ghconsole/console/auth.py", line 53, in fetch_url
    raise RedirectError("http://www.google.com")
RedirectError
INFO     2014-05-22 22:49:38,562 module.py:639] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 228
Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah @BenGrunfeld, is the handler for the request a subclass of ``MyWebappFramework``? If not, the ``handle_exception`` method won't be connected to catch the exception.

In other words, does the ``fetch_url`` call traceback to a ``MyWebappFramework`` subclass?